# Starting threads in inherited classes

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, inheritance

I wish to run threads inside classes in a project. That is, when I create an object, and then call a member function "StartThread", it will start to execute my MainThreadFunction in the object. I could re-write similar code inside all the different classes on how to start the thread but it would make more sense to use inheritance and have a base class called ThreadClass to which other classes can inherit from.

The MainThreadFunction will of course be virtual and implemented differently depending on the type of class which inherits it. The problem is, i'm not sure if i'm going about this the right way. When I implement this virtual function in the different classes and call the inherited function StartThread, should it execute the correct MainThreadFunction using this approach? Creating an object of GaugeController, I'm not sure if I should initialise the base constructor with something.

I am very new to threading and inheritance and any ideas or help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

My main query here is if this is a good design, having classes inherit from my ThreadClass to have thread characteristics.

```
//In ThreadClass.h
class ThreadClass
{
    public:
        ThreadClass();
        //virtual ~ThreadClass();
        void StartThread();
        virtual void MainThreadFunction();  
    protected:
        std::thread t;
        bool threadStop = false;

};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// In ThreadClass.cpp
ThreadClass::ThreadClass() : t()
{

}

void ThreadClass::StartThread()
{
    t = std::thread(&ThreadClass::MainThreadFunction, this);

}

void ThreadClass::MainThreadFunction()
{
  // The implementation will be different for each child class

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// In GaugeController.h
class GaugeController : public ThreadClass
{
    public:
        GaugeController(DataChannel& dc);
        ~GaugeController();
        void StartThread();
        virtual void MainThreadFunction();
        void WriteData(float data);

};
```

Comment: I am sorry for asking, but does your code compile? Because, when I was using MS' threading mechanism (CreateThread) - you couldn't start a thread with non-static class method (since it is tied to the object, and can't be called out of the context of the object).

Comment: What is `thread` in `ThreadClass` above?

Comment: @JohannGerell My guess would be: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/

Comment: Hi, I have omitted much code sorry. I am using std::thread. It all compiled fine when I had all the same logic inside the GaugeController class but i'm now trying to shift the thread starting functionality out of the class

Comment: @Engineer999, and what exactly isn't working? Did you try your code yourself? It seems to behave correctly to me (well, except not waiting for your thread to finish, if your main thread runs out of stuff to do before your worker threads do).

Comment: My problem was , In my GaugeController constructor, I was initialising t() and it didn't recognise what t was. I just realised that it would be already be done in the parent constructor

Comment: @Engineer999 Well, to be fair, you didn't that explicit initialization in the base class as well. Since the default constructor would've been called by compiler anyway.

Comment: This post has been put on hold because it is off topic . ???  This is really too much. Everything I ask here, someone has got a problem with somehow. How is it off -topic? I feel it's a good question from a C++ learner not familiar with multi-threading. Not only would I learn something from the answers but others could too

Answer (score -1):

You are "kind of" making a wrapper for `std::thread`, that's what you wanna use. So you're probably looking for something like this:

```
//In ThreadClass.h
class ThreadClass
{
    public:
        ThreadClass();
        virtual ~ThreadClass() {}
        void StartThread();
        virtual void MainThreadFunction() = 0; // this good for you
    protected:
        std::thread t;
        bool threadStop = false;

};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// In ThreadClass.cpp
ThreadClass::ThreadClass() : t()
{
}

void ThreadClass::StartThread()
{
    t = std::thread(&ThreadClass::MainThreadFunction, this);
}

// you must join your thread!
void ThreadClass::join()
{
    t.join();
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// In GaugeController.h
class GaugeController : public ThreadClass
{
    public:
        GaugeController(DataChannel& dc);
        virtual ~GaugeController() {}
        void StartThread();
        virtual void MainThreadFunction();
        void WriteData(float data);

};
```

- Use a `join()`! By default a thread from `std::thread` is joinable,
  so you need to call `join()` in order to wait the thread to finish
  its job. Other alternative is to detach your thread... Google for it,
  so you can understand better the difference between joinable threads
  and detached threads.
- virtul destructors are 99% of times a good idea! keep them. they are useful for a correct cleaup of your instances according to the class hierarchy.
- notice the `= 0` in the definition of `MainThreadFunction`. It's **optional**, but I think it fits good for you. You basically don't need to implement a method that doesn't do anything, once `ThreadClass` must be extended. You turn your `ThreadClass` in a abstract class.

Comment: Wagner, Inside the destructor I was doing threadStop = true and then t.join() in order to wait for the thread to finish before destruction of the object. Should I join the thread before the destructor tho? Cheers

Comment: downvote: `bool threadStop = false;` is not thread safe, at least use atomics.

Comment: it doesn't need to be atomic.

Comment: @WagnerPatriota If you set it from the main thread, and read it from the `thread t`, you'll encounter data race.

Comment: yes, but it won't interfere in this case. it's not always that you have data race that you need atomic variables. read about how barriers work and you will understand. in this case a non-atomic would work. and, in fact, I just fixed his code, keeping as close as the original as possible. this variable is not even being used.

Comment: I think it implied that `threadStop` should be used in `MainThreadFunction`, and I still don't really understand why it'll not cause data race. Could you help me with it?

Comment: I didn't say it won't cause data race. I said that "not always that you HAVE data race you need atomic variables". the data race WILL happen here and NO PROBLEM (again, for THIS specific case), because the WORST thing that may happen is you get an old value for variable... ok, in a next time you have it updated naturally and then you exit the loop with no problem. I use this all time time in all platforms and operating systems, server, mobile, etc. Nothing ever failed... don't worry.